# How to Bake a Bump Map from a Poly Mesh

Tags: bump

I am wondering how I can get a bump map from a high poly mesh in Blender. While using Cycles. 
If I try it with Blender Render I am still not getting the results I want.

If this is not possible then how can I create a bump map from a normal map? Maybe with Photosho?

Please Help

Regards

Comment: Normal maps and bump maps are two completely different things. If you want to convert normal to bump, you'd have to use a converter, there are a couple of free ones, I forgot their names, but e.g. crazybump (trial) should be able to do that. 
When you say "not [...] the results I want", what results are you getting?

Comment: In Blender Render I am getting just pitch black maps and in cycles render, by trying "Emit" in an Emmission shader I still get "purple" colored normal maps... But I want those stunning greyscale heightmaps.

Comment: Oh and can you please explain me the difference between a normal map and a height/bump? I mean, sure, the difference is obvious but for the result, what does it matter? Are there any avantages?

Comment: Here's the short version: 
bump tells a shader to map a bump or a dent (or nothing at 0.5). It should only be used for actual displacement. The bump map can be converted to a normal map in cycles, but the result is not very good compared to the results of specialized bump mapping tools. 
A normal map offsets the direction of a light ray that hits the surface, simulating a bump, but it also has a direction x and y instead of just z (where z is the normal of your poly)

Comment: For some reason I didn't see your first comment until now. Anyways, I don't know what you want to achieve by using emit? Because your textures are black? They have nothing to do with lighting, they gather geometry information. There are a ton of things that can go wrong while baking (a shortcoming in Blender, if you ask me) but I need to see your baking setup to tell you more, in general it works, and I would suggest you don't use Cycles for that kind of baking.